# Store and use both interface and Node

Tags: java, javafx, interface

Okay, so I'm working on a JavaFX soft. I'm using a BorderPane, and let's imagine I want to have forms to be on the right. The user can switch with a menu between forms. I want to be able to propose the user to save/finish the form (or not) before changing to another form.

So I took a simple solution, an interface, that I will implement on my custom nodes:

```
public interface Closable {
    public abstract void close();
}
```

I will store them in my custom BorderPane called ApplicationMainWindow :

```
public class ApplicationMainWindow extends BorderPane {
    private HashMap<Pos,Closable> windowContent;
}
```

Now I will set up the ApplicationMainWindow procedure that I will use to check the current Node on the right before changing it, and here come the issue

```
public void changeRight(Closable c) {
    this.windowContent.get(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT).close();
    this.setRight((Node)c);
    this.windowContent.put(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT,c);
}
```

Now well as you can see, it's not clean at all because it assumes that I will only implement Closable in a Node children classes. Now, of course, I could ensure that it implements Closable and extends from Node (or a child) doing so:

```
public void changeRight(Closable c,Node n) {
    this.windowContent.get(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT).close();
    this.setRight(n);
    this.windowContent.put(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT,c);
}
```

But it still won't be clean at all, because we would have called for the method looking like this:

```
mainWindow.changeRight((Closable)myForm,(Node)myForm);
```

Is there a better / more clean design allowing to implements this feature?

Comment: `public <T extends Node & Closeable> changeRight(T n) { this.windowContent.get(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT).close();
    this.setRight(n);
    this.windowContent.put(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT,n); }`

Answer (score 0):

Well as I expect, there was an easy and clean solution, provided by my teacher. So here is my Closable interface :

```
public interface Closable {
    public abstract void close();
}
```

Well all I need to do it create a new interface that will extends from Closable with a getNode() method :

```
public interface NodeClosable extends Closable {
    public Node getNode();
}
```

Now all I need to do is implement this interface in my form class

```
public class MyForm extends VBox implements NodeClosable {

    public Node getNode() {
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        /* some code here */
    }
}
```

and in my ApplicationMainWindow all I need to have / do is :

```
public class ApplicationMainWindow extends BorderPane {
    private HashMap<Pos,NodeClosable> windowContent;

    public void changeRight(NodeClosable nc) {
        this.windowContent.get(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT).close();
        this.setRight(n.getNode());
        this.windowContent.put(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT,c);
    }
```

Can probably just set both methods in one interface.